# Logging in users after they register using passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

After a user signs up, I'd like them to automatically be logged in. I read online to use req.login(), but it doesn't seem to be working. The user is added to the database, but aren't logged in. Can someone point me the right direction?

```
        if(type == 'student'){
            User.saveStudent(newUser, newStudent, function(err, user){
                console.log('Student saved');
                req.login(newUser, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            })
        } else {
            User.saveInstructor(newUser, newInstructor, function(err, user){
                console.log('Instructor saved');
                req.login(newUser, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            })
        }

        res.redirect('/classes');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are all your `app.use` things setup right for the session, cookies, passport init, etc?  Can you post that code if you're not sure? Is logging in after registering (I mean, using the normal login workflow for a returning user) working?

Comment: Just updated it with the app.js I think I included everything. Yup I am able to login after registering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH, I see what's happening. You're doing a `res.redirect()` outside the callback where you save the user.  It's probably redirecting prior to the login cookie being set.

Move the `res.redirect()` into the res.login() callback and you should be good.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!